# numbers cannot follow characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string that numbers cannot follow characters

For example, these should all match:

- abc-123
- 123-abc
- 123-abc-123
- abc-123-abc

not match:

- abc123
- 123abc
- abc1
- a1b2

Please help me to find a javascript regex.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What expressions have you been trying and which examples fail? Also, why is `123abc` considered invalid?

Comment: Characters cannot be preceded by numbers，like a1b2c3 or 1ab2c3

Comment: That's not what your question says

Comment: sorry,My description is not clear enough

Comment: 1.) You want to alternate between letters and digits, so `abc-abc` or `123-123` are not valid, right? 2.) What about single numbers or words e.g. `abc` or `123`, are they valid? 3.) Is the hyphen at start or end valid? E.g. `-abc-123`...

Comment: For *alternating* numbers and letters with hyphen between: [`^\b\d*(?:\b-?[a-z]+-\d+)*-?\b[a-z]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/NsogT7/3) or [`^(?:\d+-?\b(?!\d)|[a-z]+-?\b(?![a-z]))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NsogT7/1) (use [`i`-flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase#examples) to make `[a-z]` match `[a-zA-Z]`).

Answer (score 2):

To match strings that contain only letters separated by numbers, you can use the following regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

This regular expression will match strings that start and end with letters, and have a number in between. The letters and the number must be separated by a hyphen.

For example, you can use the following code to test this regular expression:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;

console.log(regex.test("abc-123")); // should return true
console.log(regex.test("123-abc")); // should return true
console.log(regex.test("123-abc-123")); // should return true
console.log(regex.test("abc-123-abc")); // should return true
console.log(regex.test("abc123")); // should return false
console.log(regex.test("123abc")); // should return false
console.log(regex.test("abc1")); // should return false
console.log(regex.test("a1b2")); // should return false
```

This code defines a regular expression using the pattern described above, and then uses the test method to check if various strings match the pattern. The test method returns a boolean indicating whether the string matches the pattern or not.

**Edited, since the question changed (I am still not sure if it is correct).**

Comment: thx, but can match abc-123 or 123-abc, not match abc123, a1b2c3, 123abc